# How to search a particular place in google maps sdk in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Suppose I am writing a New york in UITextfield and search it via google map sdk in ios.Can i get latitude and longitude of new york via sdk.I want a google map api link like this.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

sorry for bad english writing skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API which u used to fetch Geocode will work but you have to pass the correct sensor,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

and got the result,
...
 "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4219985,
               "lng" : -122.0839544
            }
...

Sensor - Attribute used to find whether your current location can be tracked or not.

Hope this answers your question.

Thanks,
Prasanna